# How to specify null value character for `csv.reader`?

Tags: python, csv

I want to read "csv" file with `\u0000` as null, `\u0001` as line terminator and `u0002` as delimiter. For last two there is two parameters:

```
csv.reader(csvfile, lineterminator='\u0001', delimiter='\u0002')
```

Is there parameter for null value character?

Comment: What do you mean `\u0000` as null? Are you saying you want a line that reads `"\u0000\u0002val_1\u0002\val_2\u0001"` to be interpreted as `[None, "val_1", "val_2"]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that . I already do it somehow with `csv.DictReader(text.replace('\u0000', '').split('\u0001'), delimiter='\u0002')`. It looks messy, so I'm looking for better way. It is also interesting for me is it possible to specify the types for columns: ints, strs, uuids ... but it is another question

Comment: That is the best way that I can think of. If `\u0000`s are expected to be in the same column(s) every time, you could read without replacement, and replace the values in the dicts at the correct keys, that would probably be faster

Comment: How exactly did you create this file? Also, does it actually contain null characters, or does it contain backslash-escape sequences? What do you see if you try opening the CSV file in a text editor?

Comment: Actually contain null characters. The customer insisted on such an ugly format. I didn’t understand the reasons. Text editor wont open this files

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) instead since it supports an alternative character as a line terminator and would convert occurrences of `'\u0000'` into `np.nan` so that you can easily replace them with `None` using the `DataFrame.replace` method.

Note that you would have to know in advance the number of columns in the CSV in order to pass to it a range of numbers as column names. You can then convert the dataframe to a numpy array for iteration:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv = io.StringIO('\u0000\u0002a\u0002b\u0001\u0000\u0002c\u0002d\u0001')
for a, b, c in pd.read_csv(
        csv, names=range(3), lineterminator='\u0001', delimiter='\u0002'
    ).replace(np.nan, None).to_numpy():
    print(a, b, c)
```

This outputs:

```
None a b
None c d
```

You can also convert the numpy array to a list of lists with the `tolist` method:

```
print(pd.read_csv(
    csv, names=range(3), lineterminator='\u0001', delimiter='\u0002'
).replace(np.nan, None).to_numpy().tolist())
```

which outputs:

```
[[None, 'a', 'b'], [None, 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to preprocess the file before passing it to the CSV reader, because two of your expectations cannot be met by the CSV reader alone:

- no "null" value
- `lineterminator` only applies to the writer, from the docs[^1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator):

  > The reader is hard-coded to recognise either `'\r'` or `'\n'` as end-of-line, and ignores *lineterminator*. This behavior may change in the future.

Since two of your characters don't have meaning to the CSV reader, I think you'll need to preprocess the file and replace them with meaningful values.

Given an input file like:

```py
with open("input.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("\u0000\u0002val_1\u0002val_2\u0001")
    f.write("\u0000\u0002val_3\u0002val_4\u0001")
```

```
hexdump -C input.csv 
00000000  00 02 76 61 6c 5f 31 02  76 61 6c 5f 32 01 00 02  |..val_1.val_2...|
00000010  76 61 6c 5f 33 02 76 61  6c 5f 34 01              |val_3.val_4.|
0000001c
```

Maybe preprocess the file like:

```py
with (
    open("input.csv") as f_in,
    open("fixed.csv", "w") as f_out,
):
    txt = f_in.read()
    txt = txt.replace("\u0001", "\n")  # add line endings that CSV reader recognizes
    txt = txt.replace("\u0000", "")  # go ahead and clear out \u0000
    f_out.write(txt)
```

Then read the CSV like:

```py
import csv

with open("fixed.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\u0002")
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

to get row variables that look like:

```py
['', 'val_1', 'val_2']
['', 'val_3', 'val_4']
```

I opted to clear the `\u0000` values because the CSV reader doesn't natively interpret empty as None; the writer will interpret None as empty. Still, an empty field in a CSV file is normal.

If you don't (want to) replace `\u0001` in the preprocess, the internal rows will look like:

```py
['\x00', 'val_1', 'val_2']
['\x00', 'val_3', 'val_4']
```

and you could handle `'\x00'` as you see fit.